# How do I write this in JavaScript if else?

Tags: javascript

I am looking to have a password field with a submit button that on click of submit, if the password enter is not 12345, and error message will appear, but if 12345 is entered, it will go to www.URL.com

Comment: What kind of security is that? If it's in JavaScript anyone would be able to crack that.

Comment: What have you tried so far? There are about 42,000 different ways you could skin this proverbial cat.

Comment: A password secured by Javascript is no more secure than no password at all.

Comment: Never implement a login form with pure JavaScript. You need a server technology for security.

Comment: If you want a JS based login, I would recommend at least using AJAX to call a login script. I wouldn't leave the password in the open to be viewed by anyone that knows how to read code...

Comment: a password in Javascript is not secured, but he can still use it if the content is just not ment to be available but not secret. some kind of "blocus" or search engine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 function checkIfValid(){
     var yourField = document.getElementById('password').value;
     if (yourField == "12345") { 
          window.location.href = "http://www.google.com"; 
          return true;
      }else{
          alert("NOT GOOD");
          return false;
      }
  }
```

on your form :

```
<form name="FORMNAME" action="script.php" onSubmit="return checkIfValid()">
    <input name="password" id='password' type="password"/>
    <input type="submit" value='submit'>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

To detect a button click, you can use `onclick`:

```
document.getElementById("button").onclick = function() {
    //code here
};
```

Then, to get the value of an input, you can use `.value`:

```
var value = document.getElementById("password").value;
```

To compare it, use an `if` and the equality operator:

```
if (value == "12345")
```

You could show an "error message" with `alert` if the password is wrong:

```
alert("wrong password");
```

And use `location.href` to redirect the user if the password is good:

```
location.href = "www.url.com";
```

Note that any authentication component that relies solely on the client-side of things (ie, browser JavaScript) is not secure at all.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code:

**HTML**

```
<input type="password" id="pass" />
<input type="button" id="foo" value='Click me' />
```

**JS**

```
function addHandler(type, el, myFunction) {
    if (el.addEventListener) {
        el.addEventListener(type,myFunction,false);
    } else (el.attachEvent) {
        type = 'on' + type;
        el.attachEvent(type,myFunction);
    }
}
var button = document.getElementById('foo');

addHandler('click', button, function () {
    var pass = document.getElementById('pass').value;
    if (pass === '12345') {
        window.location = 'http://url.com/';       
    } else {
        alert('not so bad');
    }
});
```

Of course you can change the button to a submit, there's not a lot of difference.

And the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3PT5a/

Best regards!

Comment: Your `attachEvent()` code isn't correct (you have to add "on" to the event name) nor is the `else` branch of `addHandler()` (you need to use the actual event passed in, not hardcoded to "onmouseover").  Result, this code won't work in versions of IE before IE9 without fixing.

Comment: It's still not fixed.  First, you are adding each event listener twice.  Then, for `attachEvent()`, you must add "on" to the type so it's "onclick".

Comment: Yeah...fixed I'm surely taking a break! :-P

Answer (score 0):

If you are 100 % aware of what you are doing - and I am pretty sure you are not - use this:

```html
<form action="" method="post" 
  onsubmit="if(passwd.value=='myPass')location='http://example.com/';return false">
 <input type="password" name="passwd" />
 <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Besides: I know it's dirty (`passwd` instead of adding an id and calling `document.getElementById('passwd')` or at least use `this.passwd`) but notice, it's an one-liner ;)